# Android TV :Shadow Customization

Tags: android, shadow, android-tv, leanback

I am working on android tv using leanback. I want visible fading shadow for highlighted item in browse fragment row item.I am getting shadow when i change the below values

```
<dimen name="lb_material_shadow_normal_z">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_material_shadow_focused_z">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_material_shadow_details_z">60dp</dimen>
```

But this also not giving a bright shadow.Is there any way to customize color of leanback shadow or increase the thickness of shadow.

I need this type of shadow overlapped between row items

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623677/android-tv-verticalgridfragment-shadow-dimension-and-color), the recommended way of customizing the leanback's components is through overriding the styles and dimens. You need to create your own views and your own view presenters (instead of using their `ImageCardView`). With that you could set your own shadows at the presentation level.

Also, according to this [documentation](http://corochann.com/browsefragment-listrow-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-18-705.html#Shadow_customization), if you want to change the shadow effect for `ListRow`, you can modify `Presenter` class. **`setShadowEnabled`** method is used to enable/disable shadow effect.

Comment: I need that type of shadow for selected row item(updated the image).